# Why doesn't Enum.filter work with a dictionary parameter?

Tags: elixir

I'm filtering a list using [`Enum.filter/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#filter/2).

I've simplified the code to it's bare essentials to isolate what's happening, but I can't understand where it's going wrong.

Here's the code:

```
defmodule Servy.Reducer do
   alias Servy.Wildthings

   def index(%{} = bear_filter) do
      Wildthings.list_bears()
      |> Enum.filter(
         fn(bear) ->
          IO.inspect(bear_filter)
          case bear do 
             bear_filter -> true
                       _ -> false
               end
            end)
   end  
end
```

When I compile, I get these warnings, which if true would explain the problem. I neither understand why `bear_filter` is unused nor why the `_` clause is unreachable.

```
warning: variable "bear_filter" is unused (if the variable is not meant to be used, prefix it with an underscore)
  lib/servy/reducer.ex:10: Servy.Reducer.index/1

warning: this clause cannot match because a previous clause at line 10 always matches
  lib/servy/reducer.ex:11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this particular case you’d better use [`Kernel.match?/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html?#match?/2) macro:

```
Enum.filter(Wildthings.list_bears(), &match?(^bear_filter, &1))
```

or a [`Kernel.SpecialForms.for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html?#for/1) comprehension:

```
for ^bear_filter <- Wildthings.list_bears(), do: bear_filter
```

Both approaches immediately reveal that you expect somewhat magical to happen here. I’d wild guess you want to pass filter like `%{foo: 42}`. I’d suggest you go with `match?/2` directly:

```
Enum.filter(Wildthings.list_bears(), &match?(%{foo: _}, &1))
```

If you want to wrap it into a helper, you need a macro to accept `%{foo: _}`-like arguments.

Comment: You win the Internet today. I'm learning elixir, and you accurately gauged my intentions. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Elixir allows for variables to be rebound. So in your case expression, you have the branch `bear_filter -> true`. This is actually creating a new variable and always matching (which is why it is saying it is unused and why the second branch is unreachable). If you want to match against the `bear_filter` that you pass into your function, you will need to add the [pin operator](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#%5E/1). So you would change that line to `^bear_filter -> true`.

Comment: More about [pin operator `^`](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/pattern-matching.html#the-pin-operator) in _Elixir_ tutorial on the official site.

Comment: Added the ^, but now the ^bear_filter never matches. Yet, it works in iex. I'm starting to want my Erlang back.

Comment: One of the great things about Elixir is that you can just write Erlang code and call it from Elixir. You can create a `src` directory next to your `lib` directory and start putting Erlang code in there! Then mix will just build it for you like any other module.

Comment: @Jeff show the [tag:erlang] code, please, we’ll tell how to have it in [tag:elixir].

Answer (score 0):

`bear_filter -> true`

On line 10, you're pattern matching `bear_filter` to the parameter `bear` and then not using it in the resulting expression (`true` does not contain `bear_filter`).

The `_` is unreachable because `case` is used to perform pattern matching. In this case, `bear_filter` will pattern match any value passed in, causing the `bear_filter -> true` to always match and execute.